PCG (Pseudo-random Correlation Generator) for Silent OT and Beaver's Triples
I am studying this paper https://hal.science/hal-03373123/document to learn how silent OT works, but it's a bit tricky to understand for me...  So I wonder if you could explain once again like the one done in this article How to Do Beaver's Triple without a Trust Party?, which was super-helpful.
We are trying to use silent OT for designing various PPML services based on MPC. But I really want to understand how silent OT works. Especially, how the PCG for silent OT  is designed, and then how silent OT is designed based on this PCG. Then, how Beaver's triples can be generated based on such PCG.
Thanks a lot in advance.
